# Update on outbuilding grounding requirements

Tags: electrical, grounding

This isn't really a question, rather a correction to something I posted earlier.  The main building with the primary service requires it's own grounding system (of course) with the neutral bonded to the ground.  Sub-panels in the same building require the neutral isolated and a separate ground wire for the grounding bussbar (a 4 wire feed, assuming 240v) back to the main panel.   An outbuilding panel fed from the primary service panel again requires the neutral to be isolated from the ground AND the outbuilding have it's own grounding system AND requires a 4 wire service.   Others here in Washington state have told me that the outbuildings should NOT have their own grounding system and I have found that's incorrect.   So with the help from others here, consultation with the electrical inspector, I now believe we are in sync with the rest of the country.  Sorry for any confusion I may have caused.   I'll try and find the original posts and edit them based on what I now know.

Comment: This should probably be split into a proper question and a self-answer (as that's how such a thing'd be done around here :)

Comment: Thanks 3ph. Yeah, I wanted to do that.  I knew the post probably wasn't totally proper.  So you are saying I should post the question and then answer it myself?

Comment: Yes, answering your own questions is OK around here, I've done it myself before

Comment: I think many of us have asked a question and some answers were helpful but we kept at it until we figured it out then posted that answer. Your question has been answered dozens of times on this site , so you did not look very hard. But the format you have is a statement not a question.

Comment: I did look, but I got conflicting information locally. But had I looked further and found more comments regarding my subject, I could have been more sure and asked better questions of the inspector.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, outbuildings need a grounding rod.  The rod's job is to contend with **lightning** and ESD, both of which you don't want to haul into the house, since a lightning hit will vaporize that long ground wire, and be like a HEAT warhead into the rest of the wires, possibly striking an arc that would self-sustain once the lightning is done.